# Run an EXE from MSI Installation Script

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer

Is it possible to run the exe before installation of the msi.Actually i need to take the backup before installation of the msi,this all i need via the installation of the msi.
any help highly appreciable

Comment: What technology are you using to build the installer?

Comment: i'm using the visual studio setup installer

Answer (score 1):

Sure, schedule a custom action very early in the InstallExecuteSequence. No modifications to the machine should happen before the [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called.

Comment: @Mensching..sir can this be achieved via the setup which is available in the visual studio 2010.?and could you please elaborate your answer regarding the InstallExecuteSequence?

Comment: Setup and deployment projects are extremely limited. I use the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) for all my setup development for that reason. People more knowledgeable about VS2010 support would have to answer specifics there. I've added a link to InstallExecuteSequence documentation.